# Making AutoComplPop search entire project (or open buffers)?

Tags: vim

I started using [AutoComplPop](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1879) for automatic code completions.  It works great on the single file I am editing, but if file1 is making a reference to a method defined in file2, it doesn't find it.

The docs don't specify if there is a way to make it search a whole project directory, or even just all open buffers, so I can't tell if this is simply not something the plugin does, or if I need to enable something.

I was testing it out on two Ruby files, if that's relevant.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what is on the left of the cursor, ACP (like all the alternatives) decides what completion mechanism to use.

But ACP only uses Vim's default completion mechanisms: if `<C-x><C-o>` and `<C-n>`/`<C-p>` don't provide what you are looking for, ACP won't help. Try them out first.

Comment: When I do `C-n`, the thing I am looking for does come up correctly.  However, it is not appearing through ACP.  Ideas?

Comment: Do you have a `.` or some similar operator on the left of the cursor?

Comment: Yes, the example I am using is a method call on an object.

Comment: Did you see my last reply?  Does it tell you anything?  Thanks!

Comment: Well, it sounds like a bug, then. You should post an issue on the plugin's page issue tracker but I wouldn't be too hopeful: ACP is pretty much dead.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like that the cause of the problem is that ACP set the [`complete` option](http://usevim.com/2012/07/06/vim101-completion/) for its purposes to `.,w,b,k` (see line #125 in autocomplpop/plugin/acp.vim),

> ```
> call l9#defineVariableDefault('g:acp_completeOption', '.,w,b,k')
> ```

while the default value that is used when pressing `\<C-n>` is `.,w,b,u,t,i`. And it appears that the very last letter `i` actually makes the difference: for some reason vim would *not* use word from an include file opened in a buffer to complete words in another buffer. So, `b` option is not enough, `i` must also be included. Adding the following line into my .vimrc helped

```
let g:acp_completeOption = '.,w,b,u,t,i'
```

At least it worked for C++ files, but I'm not sure it fixes the problem for the case of Ruby scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Oh cool, this plugin looks a lot like [neocomplcache](https://github.com/Shougo/neocomplcache) but maybe cleaner...looks a little old. Little concerning that there are so many open tickets on that project and no updates in two years.

Anyway, according to [the documentation](https://bitbucket.org/ns9tks/vim-autocomplpop/src/13fe3d8064647e2cdf07e12840108c3f917f5636/doc/acp.txt?at=default) it doesn't...really...say. Very likely its one of the following things:

- Your `pwd`. If the root directory for your source is `some/path` then that should also be your current working directory. Try typing `:cd some/path` to see if that makes a difference.
- The runtime path `rtp`. See if adding the directory with your source files to `&rtp` does the trick.
- The `path`. Same deal as the `&rtp` setting.

Very likely this plugin is just falling back on the built in ruby omni completion functions bundled with vim. Try `help ft-ruby-omni`.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem, and I actually found a solution for this.
Apparently you have to set in your `.vimrc` file the following:

```
let g:acp_behaviorKeywordCommand = "\<C-x>\<C-i>"
```

This will make acp look in every file included by your source for completions, as if you were actually typing `<C-p>`. However, it is slow, after trying it I decided to revert using `<C-p>` when there are no matches and default behaviour in the other cases.